# How do I retrieve information from multiple textboxes? (android)

Tags: android, eclipse

**EDIT**

I now have this code:

```
public void sendMessage(View view) {
       Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
        EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_name);
        String message = editText.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message);

        EditText editText1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_age);
        String message1 = editText1.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message1);

        EditText editText2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_height);
        String message2 = editText2.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message2);

        EditText editText3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_weight);
        String message3 = editText3.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message3);

        EditText editText4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.enter_gender);
        String message4 = editText4.getText().toString();
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE, message4);

        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

How would I go about withdrawing both the information from what is in all these windows at the same time? As I would like to save it in a user profile. Currently this is my code, but I am only being given the information from "enter_gender".

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Get the message from the intent
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String message = intent.getStringExtra(NutritionHandler.EXTRA_MESSAGE);

        // Create the text view
        TextView textView = new TextView(this);
        textView.setTextSize(40);
        textView.setText(message);


        // Set the text view as the activity layout
        setContentView(textView);
    }
```

Comment: use 2 editTexts ? i don't understand your problem

Comment: copy and paster your own code and change the reference/name/id

Comment: I tried, but I get a "the local value is not used" when I create a new one. I have a class that is supposed to get the message from the intent, but it is only retrieving the first one being "enter_name".

Comment: @Maris post the second edittext code which you created

Comment: I got it working now, had just forgotten to add the new reference to all the right places. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below,

Your Xml

> 

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtName"       
    android:layout_height="40dp"    
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtName"  
    android:background="@drawable/edittext" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip" 
    android:hint="@string/hnt_name"  
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip"   
    android:inputType="textCapSentences"
    /> 

 <EditText
    android:id="@+id/edtAge" 
    android:layout_height="40dp"   
    android:layout_below="@+id/txtEmailid"  
    android:background="@drawable/edittext" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"   
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dip" 
    android:hint="@string/hnt_emailid"      
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"    

    />
```

In your Oncreate

```
 EditText name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);        
 EditText  age = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtAge);
```

Get This Value

```
   String var_name = name.getText().toString();  
   String var_age = age.getText().toString();
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think you can easily achieve it by repeating the lines 3,4 and 5 of your code to do it and just changing the id.